# Null included in string imported from rs232

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a sting that is appended to a text view from a rs232 device. Everything imports but there is some of the strings that get concatinated as if there is a null value attached to end and start of some of the data that is imported. Any idea on how to look for a null value in a string?

```
- (void)readBytesAvailable:(NSInteger)count {
    DataSource *sharedManager = [DataSource sharedManager];
    const int bufferLength = 1024;
    uint8_t buffer[bufferLength];
    NSString *s;

    NSInteger bytesRead = [session read:buffer bufferLength:bufferLength];
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        // Convert to a string - note that the remote device is sending only well-  formed UTF8 text data (e.g. no binary data, no VT100 excampe codes, etc).
        s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        AllDataTextView.text = [AllDataTextView.text stringByAppendingString:s];
```

Comment: Solved It: The data was in ASCII format and not utf-8 and the buffer length is provided by count that is sent to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are parsing the strings is wrong.

If you are reading bytes in chunks of 1024 bytes then you can easily read up only a part of some character (UTF8 characters can have length of 1, 2, 3 or even more bytes). Then when trying to parse such a chunk, you will get `nil` (`null`) because your `buffer` won't contain valid data (a partial character is invalid and it will make parsing fail).

The ideal solution would be to read all the bytes first and then convert them to text. Another solution is to detect partial characters (see UTF8 specification) and parse only the characters that are whole and keep the partial characters in the buffer until next iteration.

See [Decoding partial UTF-8 into NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912571/decoding-partial-utf-8-into-nsstring)

Comment: could you give me an example of how to read all the bytes and then convert it to a string. Thanks fot the info but I am not very clued up with this as some of the code I posted comes from a sdk I am using to download data over wifi. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Wilbe I am not sure whether this is an option for you, that depends on how your `session` works.

Comment: I had a look to determine how the session class works but it seems to be pulled from the library that is part of the SDK. I will contact the developers of the SDK maybe they can shed some light on the issue.